# Mapping between two functions

Tags: complex-analysis, polynomials

I have two functions, $f$ and $g$, that are of these forms:

$$ \left\{
\begin{array}{ccc}
f&=&ax^2 \cos (cx)+bx\sin (cx)     \hspace{2mm}~,\\
&&\\
 g&=&ax\sin (cx)-b\cos (cx)      \hspace{2mm}~.
\end{array}
\right.$$

Parameters $a$, $b$ and $c$ are positive real numbers.  Is there a 
technique for writing function $f$ based on function $g$?  That is, how does one find a function $h$ such that $f=h(g)$?

In the special case with $(a=b=c=1)$, with numerical simulation, 
I saw that function $h$ is the quadratic function. I guess that $h$ is the quadratic function for all value $a$, $b$ and $c$.

Answer (score 0):

$f\left(x\right)\sin \left(cx\right)=ax^{2}\cos \left(cx\right)\sin \left(cx\right)+bx\sin ^{2}\left(cx\right)$

$=ax^{2}\cos \left(cx\right)\sin \left(cx\right)+bx\left(1-\cos ^{2}\left(cx\right)\right)$

$=ax^{2}\cos \left(cx\right)\sin \left(cx\right)+bx-bx\cos ^{2}\left(cx\right)$

$=x\cos \left(cx\right)\left(ax\sin \left(cx\right)-b\cos \left(cx\right)\right)+bx$

$=x\cos \left(cx\right)g\left(x\right)+bx$

So:

$f\left(x\right)=x\tan ^{-1}\left(cx\right)g\left(x\right)+bx\sin ^{-1}\left(cx\right)$

Answer (score 0):

First I would appreciate your help in advance. I think the third line is not correct because you remove the term $bx$.
 I did find no reason why do you delete this term. If we want to correct your answer from the third line, we have:

\begin{eqnarray}
&=&x\cos(cx)(ax\sin(cx)-b\cos(cx))+bx\, , \\
&=&x\cos(cx)g(x)+bx\, .
\end{eqnarray}

so:
$$f(x)=x\tan^{-1}(cx)g(x)+bx\tan^{-1}(cx)\, .$$